# Transfer learning behavior on custom image dataset

Tags: neural-networks

I am trying to apply transfer learning, especially fine-tuning by freezing layers and allowing the other ones to backprop.

I am using InceptionV3 with ImageNet weights on my own custom data.
I have around 76 classes, and each class has different objects in it.
For example, class x has persons, cars, trees and so on.

I suspect that ImageNet data is kind of uniformly distributed, namely that each class has objects of that type only. For example, the cat class has cat images only.
However, my data is a mixture of Gaussians, namely each class has different objects in it as described above.

The problem is that the model doesn't converge at all with this kind of data.
Does it happen due to the variation or would there be any other reason?

Answer (score 0):

In short, yes, it happens due to the "variation" that you defined.

The reason behind the model not converging is that your classes themselves have become something that has no characteristic features as there are objects of many different ImageNet classes in each of them, as you mentioned previously.

Imagine some heaps of pictures (initial classes) on the floor (feature space). All of these classes have their center (average representation) close to the majority of pictures. The model basically distinguishes between the classes based on these averages.

In your case, the heaps are mixed and separated on new heaps more or less arbitrarily. This shifts the initial centers closer to each other, making the new classes nearly indistinguishable from one another.

That's why the model is not able to reach any meaningful results.

Comment: The last point that you mentioned i.e. 'heaps are mixed and separated on new heaps more or less arbitrarily' should be applicable for training started from scratch, right?. I mean even if i start training from scratch, it should not converge, but it converges well though i could not understand/visualize the reason. Any comments on this behavior? . And embeddings that i extract from that model is not efficient as InceptionV3 pre-trained model.

Comment: @VeeranjaneyuluTOka, I have no definitive answer to the situation when training from scratch allows to converge. My guess is that it happens due to the network creating feature space that can distinguish the mixed classes well enough. 

To test this guess, you can try to transfer-learn this converged model on usual ImageNet dataset.

Comment: @VeeranjaneyuluTOka How did it go?